# Insert a graphic within a sentence nicely?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I am using string diagrams that I draw in Illustrator a lot, and I would like to draw them within a sentence.

When I just put `\includegraphics{...}` in the text, the image appears but its bottom is aligned with the text. I would like the center of the image aligned with the text, analogous to how in `\displaystyle` the center of the sum or integral is aligned with the text rather than its bottom.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics{...}\end{tabular}`

Comment: or use `adjustbox` package which adds keys to `\includegraphics` for vertical alignement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics{...}\end{tabular}
```

More complex, but perhaps handier,

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

and then

```
\includegraphics[valign=M]{...}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Some text \includegraphics[height=3ex]{example-image-1x1} some text

\bigskip

Some text
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[width=3ex]{example-image-1x1}\end{tabular}
some text

\bigskip

Some text \includegraphics[height=3ex,valign=M]{example-image-1x1} some text

\bigskip

Some text \includegraphics[height=3ex,valign=m]{example-image-1x1} some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want full control on the amount of raising or lowering, use `\raisebox`:

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics{...}}
```

Instead of `\height` or a multiple thereof, you can use an explicit length.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!